# Can't get data from ZenMoney API (OAuth2)

Tags: python-3.x, api, oauth-2.0

I am not good in AOuth2, so I am using ready for work specific library for ZenMoney:
https://github.com/Felixoid/python-zenmoney

Here you can see the "simplest way to start":

```
oauth = OAuth2('ge9e572374ec89f3a1562e4*******', '2d14e80****', '***tin@nes.ru', 'x3bTm***')
api = Request(oauth.token)
diff = api.diff(Diff(**{'serverTimestamp': 1}))
```

(I have hidden my credentials above)

After that, according to description in library, I can use "diff" to get data from API (https://github.com/zenmoney/ZenPlugins/wiki/ZenMoney-API#principles)

But all that I got is:

```
diff

> <diff.Diff at 0x171fcfd92e0>
```

Calling attributes show me the same:

```
diff.transaction

> [<transaction.Transaction at 0x171fd0fe670>,
 <transaction.Transaction at 0x171fd0fe6a0>,
 <transaction.Transaction at 0x171fd0fe6d0>,
 <transaction.Transaction at 0x171fd0fe700>,
 <transaction.Transaction at 0x171fd0fe730>,
 <transaction.Transaction at 0x171fd0fe760>,
 <transaction.Transaction at 0x171fd0fe790>,
 <transaction.Transaction at 0x171fd0fe7c0>,
 <transaction.Transaction at 0x171fd0fe7f0>,
 <transaction.Transaction at 0x171fd0fe820>,
 <transaction.Transaction at 0x171fd0fe850>,
 <transaction.Transaction at 0x171fd0fe880>,
 <transaction.Transaction at 0x171fd0fe8b0>,
 <transaction.Transaction at 0x171fd0fe8e0>, 
...
```

After diving in the code behind the library, I still dont know how to get data in json format or something like this

As I said above, I have never deal with AOuth2, but I was working with REST API, so may be this question can be obvious and I am doing something fundamentally wrong

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this construction for example (get yestarday's transaction):

```
import sys
from unidecode import unidecode
from datetime import date, timedelta
from zenmoney import *


yesterday=date.today()- timedelta(days=1)
yesterday=yesterday.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

oauth = OAuth2('xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx')
api = Request(oauth.token)
#diff = api.diff(Diff(**{'serverTimestamp': 0}))
diff = api.diff(Diff(**{'serverTimestamp': 1}))

zen_transaction = ZenObject.to_dict(diff.transaction)
zen_transaction = sorted(zen_transaction, key=lambda k: k['date'])
for item in zen_transaction:
    if item['date']==yesterday:
        print(item)
```

Comment: This code also doesn't work for me. I get "code 400" or just nothing, depends from registration to get access token. May be problems at the stage of secret token registration? Can you please advise me what should I insert during the registration in the following fields: "App site url:" and "OAuth callback point url:" ? I have tried different options and first of all my local host data